# Why does Google list "brief" as an antonym for "detailed"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, vocabulary, word-difference

**brief** means *short, in few words*

**detailed** means *having many details*

Why are they antonyms? A detailed thing can be brief too. And a brief thing can also be detailed (concise)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me ask you a question, do you think that **few** and **many** are antonyms?
Those two words appear in your definitions for **brief** and **detailed** respectively. If you describe something briefly, usually you are going to use **less** words than if you explain it detailedly.

According to the Oxford Dictionary

[**brief**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brief)

> Concise in expression; using **few** words.

[**detailed**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/detailed)

> Having **many** details or facts; showing attention to detail.

---

We are talking here about **brief** as an adjective. A plan can be **briefed** [verb], explained **detailedly**, to the ones that have to execute it.

As verbs, I think that they are not exactly synonyms either.

According to the Oxford Dictionary

**[brief](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brief)**

> **Instruct** or inform (someone) thoroughly, especially in preparation for a task.

[**detail**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/detail)

> Give full information about

Notice that a **briefing** implies not only to give information, full or not, but to instruct someone. You have to explain the information given in order to accomplish a task.

Comment: as verbs they are synonyms? 

Comment: @user82287 Not exactly. I've updated my answer.

Comment: why did you use either after not exactly synonyms either. wouldn't either make an implication that I'd asked are brief and detailed synonyms (as adjective)

Comment: @user82287 I mean: "brief and detailed are not synonyms as adjectives and they are not synonyms as verbs either".

Comment: Sorry dude I'm not sure this is right, certainly a little confusing. The OP is talking strictly about the adjectives. I see you acknowledge that but getting into the verbs is just confusing.

Comment: @Astralbee OP has asked in the comments, I was just trying to help.

Comment: @RubioRic I would say that "to brief" someone and "to detail" *are* synonyms. They both mean to give someone information.

Comment: @Astralbee I think that "to brief" implies not just to give the information. I may be wrong but I don't deserve a downvote just for that.

Comment: @Astralbee Notice the presence of "instruct" in the definition of "to brief"

Comment: @RubioRic We're not just here for the votes dude, we are here to answer questions correctly. You got one upvote, probably from the OP who accepted your answer, and with all due respect to folks asking questions, if they knew the right answer they wouldn't be asking.

Comment: @Astralbee Ok, you're right about the votes but do you care to explain exactly what is wrong in my answer?

Comment: @RubioRic It doesn't fully answer the question of "*Why are they antonyms?*", it gets bogged down talking about irrelevant verbs, and it never addreses the source of the OP's confusion which is that "*a detailed thing can be brief too. And a brief thing can also be detailed (concise)*".

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> "A detailed thing can be brief too."

You are technically correct, although it would be highly unusual to describe something as "*detailed and brief*". It sounds contradictory. The correct way to describe something like that would be either as as *succinct* or *concise*. But these don't necessarily mean "short" either. They mean that a piece contains only necessary information. A lengthy document could be described as "concise" if it contains only what is necessary and explains each point in the most concise manner. When something *is* short as well as concise people tend to say "*brief and to the point*".

You couldn't say that *everything* that is brief is also detailed, and so I agree with the statement that "brief" and "detailed" *are* antonyms. In isolation they do imply the opposite - "brief" means that something is notably short, whereas "detailed" means that it includes a lot of information.

Likewise "*concise*" would be the antonym of "*wordy*", or "*long-winded*".

Comment: after putting more thought on it I think neither a detailed thing can be brief nor vice versa. And even if something is concise it would mean that it has the main facts(details) about that particular thing in brief. but detailed means having many details (whether important or less important).  So I was wrong